# How do I compare boolean values in a class?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to define a boolean function that compares two other boolean values and returns true if both of them are false. What is wrong with my code?

```
//this is the header file
class Fraction
{
    public:
        //default constructor:
        Fraction();

        //parameterized constructor:
        Fraction(int initNum, int initDen);

        int GCD(int a, int b);
        int LCM (int a, int b);
        Fraction Add(Fraction otherFraction);
        Fraction Multiply(Fraction otherFraction);
        Fraction Divide(Fraction otherFraction);
        void Reduce();
        void Write();
        bool IsEqual(Fraction otherFraction);
        bool IsLessThan(Fraction otherFraction);
        bool IsGreaterThan(Fraction otherFraction);
        Fraction Reciprocal();

        //Getters:
        int GetDenominator();
        int GetNumerator();


    private:
        int numerator;
        int denominator;
};

//this is the implementation file
#include <iostream>
#include "Fraction.h"

using namespace std;

//default constructor:
Fraction::Fraction()
{
    numerator = 0;
    denominator = 1;
}

//parameterized constructor:
Fraction::Fraction(int initNum, int initDen)
{
    numerator = initNum;
    denominator = initDen;
}

void Fraction::Write()
{
    cout << numerator << "/" << denominator;
}

int Fraction::GetDenominator()
{
    return denominator;
}

int Fraction::GetNumerator()
{
    return numerator;
}

int GCD(int a, int b)
{
    if (b == 0)
        return a;
    else
        return GCD(b, a%b);
}

int LCM (int a, int b)
{
    return (a*b)/GCD(a,b);
}

void Fraction::Reduce()
{
    int gcd = GCD(numerator, denominator);
    numerator /= gcd;
    denominator /= gcd;
}

Fraction Fraction::Reciprocal()
{
    int num = numerator;
    int den = denominator;
    int num1 = den;
    int den1 = num;
    Fraction recFraction(num1, den1);
    return recFraction;
}

Fraction Fraction::Multiply(Fraction otherFraction)
{
    int num1 = numerator;
    int num2 = otherFraction.numerator;
    int den1 = denominator;
    int den2 = otherFraction.denominator;
    int prodNum = (num1 * num2);
    int prodDen = (den1 * den2);
    Fraction prodFraction(prodNum, prodDen);
    prodFraction.Reduce();
    return prodFraction;
}

Fraction Fraction::Divide(Fraction otherFraction)
{
    Fraction quotient;
    Fraction::Multiply(otherFraction.Reciprocal());
    return quotient;
}

Fraction Fraction::Add(Fraction otherFraction) 
{
    int lcm = LCM(denominator, otherFraction.denominator);
    int num1 = numerator * (lcm/denominator);
    int num2 = otherFraction.numerator * (lcm/otherFraction.denominator);
    int newNum = num1 + num2;
    Fraction newFraction(newNum, lcm);
    newFraction.Reduce();
    return newFraction;
}

bool Fraction::IsEqual(Fraction otherFraction)
{
    Reduce();
    otherFraction.Reduce();
    int num1 = numerator;
    int num2 = otherFraction.numerator;
    int den1 = denominator;
    int den2 = otherFraction.denominator;
    if (num1 == num2 && den1 == den2)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

bool Fraction::IsLessThan(Fraction otherFraction)
{
    int lcm= LCM(denominator, otherFraction.denominator);
    int num1 = numerator * (lcm/denominator);
    int num2 = otherFraction.numerator * (lcm/otherFraction.denominator);
    if (num1 < num2)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

bool Fraction::IsGreaterThan(Fraction otherFraction)
{
    return !IsLessThan(otherFraction) && !IsEqual(otherFraction);


}
```

Edited to show all of the implementation file. The compiler is now outputting the following:

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\BIRCHP~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccg3Y7E4.o:fraction.cpp:(.text+0x125): undefined reference to `Fraction::GCD(int, int)'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\BIRCHP~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccg3Y7E4.o:fraction.cpp:(.text+0x25c): undefined reference to `Fraction::LCM(int, int)'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\BIRCHP~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccg3Y7E4.o:fraction.cpp:(.text+0x344): undefined reference to `Fraction::LCM(int, int)'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I've checked over everything multiple times and cannot find anything wrong with it. I'm trying to compile the implementation file in conjunction with the driver file.

Comment: `if(Fraction::IsLessThan() == false) && (Fraction::IsEqual() == false )` should be `if((Fraction::IsLessThan() == false) && (Fraction::IsEqual() == false ))`. Also, you are trying to call `Fraction::IsLessThan()` and `Fraction::IsEqual()` without any input parameters, even though you defined them both to have an input argument.

Answer (score 3):

You declare `bool IsLessThan(Fraction otherFraction)`, which means a function called `IsLessThan` that takes a `Fraction` as a parameter and returns a `bool`. However, you later try to call it as `Fraction::IsLessThan()`, as if it were a function that took no parameter. Provide a parameter and it will work.

As for GCD and LCM, you're declaring `Fraction::GCD` and `Fraction::LCM` but never defining them. Instead, you're defining two unrelated global functions called `GCD` and `LCM`, because you forgot the `Fraction::`.

Comment: After doing that, it still isn't working. Updated code and compiler errors below: ````bool Fraction::IsGreaterThan(Fraction otherFraction)
{
 if (Fraction::IsLessThan(otherFraction) == false) && (Fraction::IsEqual(otherFraction) == false)
  return true;
  else
   return false;
 
 
}````

Comment: ````fraction.cpp: In member function 'bool Fraction::IsGreaterThan(Fraction)':
fraction.cpp:123:55: error: expected identifier before '(' token
  if (Fraction::IsLessThan(otherFraction) == false) && (Fraction::IsEqual(otherFraction) == false)
                                                       ^
fraction.cpp:129:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^````

Comment: @BirchPoirier You need parentheses around the entire `if` expression.

Comment: Ok, having done that now, and forgive me for my ignorance, but now I'm not getting an error exactly, but my program is not compiling still. The compiler output is below:

Comment: ````c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\BIRCHP~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccpNnl3a.o:fraction.cpp:(.text+0x125): undefined reference to `Fraction::GCD(int, int)'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\BIRCHP~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccpNnl3a.o:fraction.cpp:(.text+0x25c): undefined reference to `Fraction::LCM(int, int)'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe````

Comment: ````C:\Users\BIRCHP~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccpNnl3a.o:fraction.cpp:(.text+0x344): undefined reference to `Fraction::LCM(int, int)'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status````

Comment: @BirchPoirier Either you forgot to actually write the code for those functions, or you forgot to compile the file that you did so in.

Comment: That's the thing: I did define them, and in the same file, and they have no errors. I'm trying to compile the implementation and driver files at the same time, if that makes a difference.

Comment: @BirchPoirier Edit your question and post all the code for that file so we can see the definitions of all the functions.  Either you didn't declare them with the right parameters or you didn't mark them as belonging to the class' namespace.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah I've edited the question with the entire implementation file and header file. I think you're right about marking the namespace for GCD and LCM, because those were missing. It compiles now. Thanks for your help. However, if you still see something wrong with the code, I'd appreciate any tips.

Comment: @BirchPoirier Yep, something's wrong with the code. See the new bottom paragraph of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think your function needs parameters, maybe try this:

```
 if ((Fraction::IsLessThan(otherFraction) == false) && (Fraction::IsEqual(otherFraction) == false) )
    return true;
 else
     return false;
```

Also you are missing another parenthesis in the if-statement

Answer (score 0):

Syntactically, you need to also pass the other fraction that the functions expect, and you also need parentheses around the whole `if` condition. You also don't need to write `Fraction::` all the time. It's not needed:

```
if ((IsLessThan(otherFraction) == false) && (IsEqual(otherFraction) == false))
```

But comparisons to `true` and `false` are redundant. You can just write:

```
if (!IsLessThan(otherFraction) && !IsEqual(otherFraction))
```

But this is still redundant. You don't need an `if` statement at all. You can just do:

```
return !IsLessThan(otherFraction) && !IsEqual(otherFraction);
```

Finally, in order to avoid the parameters from being copied on every function call, you should change the parameter type of your functions from `Fraction otherFraction` to `const Fraction& otherFraction`:

```
bool Fraction::IsGreaterThan(const Fraction& otherFraction)
{
    return !IsLessThan(otherFraction) && !IsEqual(otherFraction);
}
```

In this specific case, not using a `const` reference doesn't incur any overhead, since your `Fraction` class only has two `int` members. But in general, passing by `const` reference when you don't store the parameter somewhere is recommended.